# XAML Text Formatting in MultiBinding

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to format a concatenated Label with different Formats and also different orientations (left- and right-aligned). Have somebody any Idea how to make that?

How to make the {0} string bold and left- and the {1} string normal and right-aligned to the screen?

my xml:

```
    <Label>
        <Label.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}      {1}">
                <Binding Source="Tag:" />
                <Binding Path="Day" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Label.Text>
    </Label>
```

Comment: if you need different alignments you should use multiple labels

Comment: so i go with a horizontal Stack Layout for example?

Comment: yes, that's what I would do

Comment: you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the MultipleBinding, you could try the code below. But this could not make the {0} string bold and left- and the {1} string normal and right-aligned to the screen.

```
 <Label>
            <Label.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}      {1}">
                    <Binding Path="Model1.Day" />
                    <Binding Path="Model1.Tag" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Text>
        </Label>
```

You could use AbsoluteLayout instead.

```
 <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
        <Label Text="{Binding Path=Model1.Day}"   BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" TextColor="White"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Path=Model1.Tag}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, AutoSize, AutoSize" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" TextColor="White"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this ?

Adjust it like you want

```
   <Label>
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" ForegroundColor="Fuchsia" />
                <Span Text="{Binding LastName}" FontSize="20" />
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i couldn't figure out how to align the Text with your solution either. i went with the horizontal stack panel.

Answer (score 0):

i went now with two stack panels.
the first Vertical, the second horizontal:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="20" Padding="15">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="LblDate" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Date}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="LblDay" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Day}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="LblTimepair" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Time1}"/>
        <Label Text="-"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Time2}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="LblBreak" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding TimeBreak}"/>
        <Label Text="h"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="LblTotalTime" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding TimeTotal}"/>
        <Label Text="h"/>
    </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```